# Filter by Date then Aggregate value isn't working OData

Tags: odata

I'm trying to retrieve some data with OData, but when I send this Query : `$filter=(General eq '401000' and date(DateComptable) ge 2022-06-01T00:00:00Z and date(DateComptable) le 2022-06-30T00:00:00Z)&$apply=groupby((General),aggregate(Debit with sum as TotalDebit, Credit with sum as TotalCredit))` I'm gettng this error :

> Property or path DateComptable isn't available in the current context.
> It was removed in earlier transformation.

Any idea on how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that the groupby ALWAYS happens before the filter, so I needed to use `$apply=filter(General eq '401000' and date(DateComptable) ge 2022-06-01T00:00:00Z and date(DateComptable) le 2022-06-30T00:00:00Z)/groupby((General),aggregate(Debit with sum as TotalDebit, Credit with sum as TotalCredit))`.
Doing so, the filter is trigger before the groupby and it works smoothly